# detecting input pattern verification by the event object

Tags: javascript, html

is there a way to validate the pattern of an input by it's event object (without using a form)?

something like:

```
<input type='email' onChange={e => e.isPatternOk} />
```

Comment: You mean `<input oninput="if (re.test(this.value)) ...."`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Beat me to it :), glad you figure it out

Below uses pure css AND a js solution, pick your fancy

```css
.status * {
  display: none;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

input:valid+.status .valid {
  display: inline-block;
  background: limegreen;
}

input:invalid+.status .invalid {
  display: inline-block;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<input id="textfield" type="text" pattern=".{3,}" required/>
<div class="status">
  <span class="invalid">input is invalid</span>
  <span class="valid">input is valid</span>
</div>
<input type=button onclick="document.getElementById('js-result').innerHTML = 'Input is valid: '+ document.getElementById('textfield').validity.valid;" value="Check with JS" />
<fieldset>
  <legend>JS Result</legend>
  <div id="js-result"></div>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 1):

ok i just got it.

```
<input type='email' onChange={e => e.currentTarget.checkValidity()} />
```